# jquery jTable: Child Table Theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

How can I set a different theme explicitly for a child table .... for e.g. parent table =blue (jtable) and child table = light gray (jtable).

I've tried using `jqueryuiTheme`property. But it doesn't work.

Comment: From git `https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/288`

Comment: @cr0ss It still doesn't explain how we can define a different theme.

Comment: His link says that you can use `jqueryuiTheme` property on the table, so use this property with different values in your master and child tables. If you want more help, give us the detail of your jtable implementation